# Indexed sorting of multiple values

Tags: sorting, marklogic

Given these lines of code:

```
let order = cts.indexOrder(cts.elementReference(fn.QName('','order')))
cts.search(cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery('order','*', ['wildcarded'] ),order)
```

I get this result:

```
{"order":["a", "m"]}
{"order":"a"}
{"order":["a", "x"]}
{"order":"j"}
{"order":["j", "k", "l"]}
{"order":["j", "k"]}
{"order":["j", "k", "m"]}
{"order":"m"}
{"order":["m", "z"]}
```

Shouldn't `["a"]` sort before `["a","m"]`, and `["j","k"]` precede `["j","k","l"]`?

It seems like there is some kind of ordering, but it's not precise in this way, and I'd like to understand the rules, as we have exactly this situation in a project I'm working on.

Comment: That is not the behavior that I am seeing, using 10.0-9.1. I get `["a"]`, `["a","m"]`, `["a","x"]` and when I apply the "ascending" and "descending" option to the `cts.indexOrder` it sorts in the other direction. What version of MarkLogic are you running, and what is the index? I applied a string element range index on order with default options.

Comment: @MadsHansen  10.0-8.  String element-range (or "range element" depending on where you look) index with the root collation.